# Shell script: how to make a for loop among float number strings?

Tags: linux, shell

in shell scripts, I want to make a for loop, like

```
for(i=0.01;i<=4.0;i=i+0.01)
```

or

```
for i in seq(0.01,0.01,4.0)
```

but `$i` is a character string, not a float number

how can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $(seq 0.01 0.01 4.0); do echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer, or loop on integer and then divide by 100 to output decimals, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/137443)

Answer (score 1):

shell doesn't do floating point maths, you can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=4.0;i=i+0.01) print i}'
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.1
...
...
```

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=0.1;i=i+0.01) print i}' produces 0.01 to 0.1, but awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=0.2;i=i+0.01) print i}' only produces 0.01 to  0.19, 0.2 is not included, why?

Comment: It is nature of floating point maths that produces these anomalies. You can use: `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=0.20000001;i+=0.01) print i}'` to get it.